# user name and email address not received by PhpMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Sender email and name was not received. 
 `PhpMailer` message says email was successfully sent, but I cant get the sender email or sender name. I received only the body and subject.

Thanks

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$name = $_POST['fname'];
$mail = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subj'];
$message = $_POST['mssg'];


$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();     // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'xxxxhost.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;   // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'xxxxxx@host.com';       // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';             // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';  // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 25; // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom($mail, $name); // this value not received 
// Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('support@example.com'); // Name is optional


$mail->isHTML(true);   // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body    = $message;


if(!$mail->send()) {
echo 'Message could not be sent.';
echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo 'Message has been sent';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question isn't very clear, but I'll take a guess at what you're asking.

Don't use the submitter's email address as the From address. It's forgery and will usually mean you get rejected for SPF violations or end up in spam folders. Gmail doesn't let you use arbitrary from addresses for this reason (though you can predefine aliases in gmail prefs) and it will simply use your Username address instead.

Set the submitter's address as a reply-to (see `addReplyTo()` in PHPMailer) and your own address as the from address. This way you won't be forging anything, and replies will go to the right place. Like this:

```
$mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
$mail->setFrom('me@example.com', 'My Name');
```

It's a good idea to put those values into the message body as well in case it's an invalid email address due to a simple typo, for example `user @example.com`. The reply-to will not work, but you'll still have the data.

Comment: maybe i cant explain what i need but finally i solve it

Comment: $mail->setFrom($mail, $name); // this line of cods not working but when i direct put $_POST its work nice
$mail->setFrom($_POST['email'];, $_POST['name'];); // its working
maybe its not a right format to put cods but its working for me 
again i will tell you what i was try to say in my Qsn setFrom Value means the user email and user name was not send when i call this cods Well Thanks for your Help

Comment: You do need to set a From address, but don't use the user's values from the form, it's not safe. I'll revise my answer to provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying from Gmail server, try this (without tls encryption):

```
$mail->Host = "mail.xxxhost.com";
$mail->Port = 26;
```

OR (with tls encryption):

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587;
```

May be you need to correct in your code

```
$mail->host = "mail.xxxhost.com";
```

from

```
$mail->host = 'xxxhost.com';
```

Comment: I assume that the `xxxhost.com` was a replacement domain so probably just a typo.

Comment: Thanks for your ans well its not Gmail i use my server host wc-122.atnoc.com but i will try that too and please tell why sender email and name not received i receive msg from root@localhost